# Parse Date and Time from GET Parameter

Tags: php

Okay so I would like to pass date and time to my script using GET. Right now it checks the exact value with the database, but it contains spaces.I want to convert 1 line e.g.

```
2015-03-04-03:03:34
```

I want to verify this string matches the timestamp in my sql table which displays like:

```
2015-05-03 12:03:23
```

Thanks

Comment: how you populate this get request is it dropdown or datepicker of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex with patter *remove all between date and time*:

```
$str = '2015-03-04-03:03:34';
$str = preg_replace('~(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(.+)(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})~', '$1 $3', $str);
echo $str; // 2015-03-04 03:03:34
```

Answer (score 0):

just use strtotime($variable)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

but be aware that you may need to modify your joining characters. Forward slash (/) signifies American M/D/Y formatting, a dash (-) signifies European D-M-Y and a period (.) signifies ISO Y.M.D. thus double check your results before you apply this solution.

Comment: Why you didn't try it first?